# Swagger UI - how to uncheck the option "Send empty value" in the requestBody paremeters

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I am using swagger UI.
I can't find out how to uncheck the option "Send empty value" in the requestBody parameters.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRCzS.png)

I tried looking in the documentation and also on stackoverflow for more information but couldn't find.

I want to uncheck the option "Send empty value" by default.

Comment: Do you mean how to make the "Send empty value" checkbox _unchecked by default_?

Comment: @Helen Yes! I want it to be unchecked by default.

Comment: I have not tried something like that but It would make sense to provide a default value in order for that to be unchecked. Check https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/ and search for "default" to see the setup

Comment: Thanks! This does not help because I just want that this will be unchecked and not sent to the API.